# CS50 Pset 5 Hashtable issue

Tags: hashtable, cs50

After creating a hash table and assigning each letter to a value for the table, i am noticing the first word output by the table for the beginning of every linked list is the same word. Somehow it seems I am transferring the entire dictionary to each array in the table even though I have attempted to separate them. Any assistance would be awesome! Thanks in advance

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char *word;
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 25;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

char lowerword[LENGTH+1];
// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    int bucketfind = 0;
    int x = 0;
    for (int b = word[x]; b != '\0';b = word[x], x++)
    {
        int lowertemp = tolower(word[x]);
        if (x == 0)
        {
            bucketfind = lowertemp - 97;
        }
        char lowerfinal = lowertemp;
        lowerword[x] = lowerfinal;

        //printf("%c", lowerword[x]);
    }
    int wordlen = x + 1;
    int pr = 0;
    while (table[bucketfind] -> next != NULL)
    {
        int dwlen = strlen(table[bucketfind]-> word);
        pr++;
        //printf("%i, %i, %s, %i\n", pr, dwlen, table[bucketfind] -> word, bucketfind);
    }
    //TODO
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    int asciifirst = word[0];
    int lowerfirst = tolower(asciifirst);
    int bucketnum = lowerfirst - 97;
    return bucketnum;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
int dictwords = 0;
//char *cword = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*46);
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    char *cword = malloc(sizeof(char)*46);
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dictionary == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    int x = 0;
    while ((fscanf(dict, "%s", cword) != EOF))
    {
        node *nword = malloc(sizeof(node));
        nword -> word = cword;
        nword -> next = NULL;

        int bucket = hash(cword);
        //printf("%i\n", bucket);
        if (table[bucket] != NULL)
        {
            nword -> next = table[bucket];
            table[bucket] = nword;
        }
        else
        {
            table[bucket]= nword;
        }
        dictwords++;
    }
    fclose(dict);
return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return dictwords;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not just the first word; *every* word in the linked list is the same word (the last one read). `cword` gets 46 bytes of memory at a specific address here `char *cword = malloc(sizeof(char)*46);`. Every word from dictionary is read into that same address.

Comment: I understand my issue if allocating memory correctly which i will work on but when you say every word is the last one read, i printed out my "cwords" every time and it did return every word of the dictionary. Trying to figure it out but if you could clarify would be great!

Comment: I think i got it... by stating the nodes word was equal to cword, I failed to allocate memory to the word in the node itself and every time "cword" changed in memory, so did the node that was equal to it. To fix this I needed to allocate memory to each word in the node and actually copy over the current word so it didn't get changed every time cword did. Output seems more correct at first glance but confirming im understanding this right

Comment: Understanding seems valid.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out with this!